# Mac Appstore rejection due to OpenSSL private APIs

Tags: macos, openssl, mac-app-store

I am attempting to submit an app to the Mac Appstore. It contains receipt validation at the entry of the app. The code I use for this is dependent on OpenSSL and I downloaded version 1.0.2j and built it. After successful submission, during the review process, I was informed with this issue :

> **Your app uses or references the following non-public API(s):
>   in framework: '/usr/lib/libssl.0.9.8.dylib' +++ : ssl3_send_alert**

I don't use that function in any of my code but it comes built in with the OpenSSL. Since I don't use any network related function, I believe there should be a command that I can use to exclude this during the build of OpenSSL.

So, my question would be, if anybody knows any switch/options list for OpenSSL build which passes the Mac Appstore review process? Would be glad to any help in this matter since all my searches resulted with no information on this matter.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What does `otool -L` display for your app before archiving? My gut instinct is, is buggy Apple submission screening. They are not exactly known for high quality software. But it could be your Xcode project settings, and `otool` will tell the tale.

Comment: Well, I get this warning during the review process, so from a real person from the review team. They want me to stop using that function and I don't use it in my own code. I found the same function in one of the OpenSSL header files so that must be causing the issue. How do I use 'otool -L' by the way, does it show whether you use a private API?